# Auto layout of visible part in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I'm created a view that has an image view with only part visible. This visible part's width should be for example 100px, but total width should equal total height and screen's height. I am stuck on creating constraints for X position. Here's what I've done:[image]

So how to make visible part always 100px?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put a constraint between the image's leading edge and the container's trailing edge, with a -100 constant and uncheck "relative to margin".